# How to find a point along an vector at a variable distance

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry

I need to find the value along a vector for a given x coordinate. Like so;

[image]

I know the values of A, B and C. All of these value are variable. I need to calculate X.

I know this is possable I just can't remember my trigonometry lessons.

I'm aware of similar questions like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6466871/find-a-point-along-an-angled-line) but it only finds the mid-point.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint, Use similarity of triangles.  i.e. $AC:CX = 100:100$